# Moving Sitecore Contact from a list to another

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-exm

How to remove Sitecore Contact from a list and add it to another list programmatically? Im working on Sitecore 9.1

Answer (score -1):

You can use List Manager API to perform these tasks. ISubscriptionService has  two methods Subscribe and Unsubscribe which will fulfill your requirements. Note that ListManager API is available on CM only.

You can find more information on Sitecore documentation

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-list-manager-api.html

Comment: But where do we find this ISubscriptionService interface? It's not in Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.dll, version 5.0.0.0 (the one in Sitecore 9.3).

Comment: It should be somewhere in the documentation for 9.3. I haven't used 9.3 yet.
I wonder whoever downvoted was kind enough to explain what was wrong.